# What paths does WordPress use for itself on a domain?

Tags: domain, paths

I own a domain, www.mydomain.com, where I publish solitary webpages on some path - i.e. www.mydomain.com/mycustompath1/ , www.mydomain/mycustompath2/ , etc. 
Currently there is no content in the root of my domain, but I would like to setup a WordPress page accessible at www.mydomain.com where I make a post and link to each of my custom paths.

I would like to avoid conflicts between paths used by my solitary webpages and any paths used by a WordPress deployment. However, I do not know what paths relative to www.mydomain.com that a WordPress deployment uses - i.e. www.mydomain.com/wordpresspath1/ , www.mydomain.com/wordpresspath2/ , etc.

I would appreciate very much if someone can help shed light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from those that are files in the WordPress installation, mostly beginning with `wp-`, these are also added:

- /login/ redirects to wp-login.php
- /admin/ redirects to /wp-admin/
- /feed/ RSS feeds

Any other clashes are likely because of pages with clashing slugs, or 3rd party plugins ( you will need to ask plugin authors or test )